# How to disable a wpf window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I dont know if this is possible but, I call the following method to show a window in wpf:

```
Window window = Window.Show();
```

After the window has already loaded, I want to disable the window i.e I dont want the user to be able to close the window until some condition is met...is this possible?

I tried:

`window.IsEnabled = false`, This works but the user can still close the Window...

Comment: Usually this is quite mean, from a user interface point of view.  You very rarely want to do this, and you should have a very good reason if you do.  (Where to save unsaved data is one of the few good reasons that comes to mind.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `Closing` event and cancel if the condition is not met :

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       if (/*condition not true*/)
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

However, the user could find other means to close the window, a shutdown maybe? :)